# How to set a protection on worksheets but enable outlining and filter, being available after restart?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send a price list to the customer and need to protect worksheets ( only two). However, I want to allow grouping/outlining and filtering data. As the worksheets are supposed to be sent to the customer, I don't want to bother him with anything.

I tried to set a password with the required criteria, though anytime I reopen the workbook, the grouping/outlining is locked.

What I can think of is giving a try to PivotTable?

```
Option Explicit
Sub protection()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

 Dim strPassword As String: strPassword = "***"


    With ws1

        .Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True

    End With


    With ws2

        .Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

        .EnableOutlining = True

    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the worksheets protection for UserInterfaceOnly to work after the workbook is reopened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    protection
End Sub    

Sub protection()
    Const Password = "***"        
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
        With ws  
            .Protect Password:=Password , UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
            .EnableOutlining = True
        End With
    Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used my code first and then put your code into **ThisWorkbook**. It's the only way that works for me. I don't understand why. As I said I need to send the workbook to the customer, I am afraid that he will be prompt to allow macros upon which this code could crash. Let's say he opens the workbook, allow the macro but can't use grouping. Then he reopens the workbook, no prompts and he can use grouping. Am I right?

Comment: I had a typo in my code and removed `Unprotect` which was unnecessary.   The `Workbook_Open` fires after you clicks `Enable Content`.  The only way this will will not work is if you don't enable the content.